# When buton clicked, open new window - pyqgis

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt, connection

I'm making a plugin which has two windows. What I want to know is how to refer pushButton in one window to method which opens new window.

I have dialog *.ui files for both windows and their *.py. Should I have a method in my main_plugin.py file which opens new window? Should I have two classes in my main_plugin.py file or should I make a new file for new window 'body'? Is there anything else I should take into consideration?

Maybe someone have a code with similar button-window connection?

EDIT:
I tried to do it like dmh126 said, but something is still wrong. Here is my code I what had I changed:

plugin_dialog.py:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Symbolizacja_dialog_base.ui'))


class SymbolizacjaDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(SymbolizacjaDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

plugin_config_dialog.py:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Symbolizacja_dialog_ustawienia.ui'))


class SymbolizacjaConfigDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(SymbolizacjaConfigDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

plugin.py:

in main class (Symbolizacja):

```
from Symbolizacja_dialog import SymbolizacjaDialog
from Symbolizacja_config_dialog import SymbolizacjaConfigDialog
```

in def **init**(self, iface):

```
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
```

added new method:

```
def handleButton(self):
        self.sc = SymbolizacjaConfig(self)
        self.sc.show()
```

added new class (at the end):

```
class SymbolizacjaConfig(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(SymbolizacjaConfig, self).__init__(parent)
```

Comment: self.sc = SymbolizacjaConfig(self) edit: self.sc = SymbolizacjaConfig()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new dialog as a class, even in your main .py file.

```
class NewDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(NewDialog, self).__init__(parent)
```

Than in your main class you can put function like that:

```
...
def open_new_dialog(self):
    self.nd = NewDialog(self)
    self.nd.show()
...
```

This function creates a new dialog and display it.

Now just create a connection in your main class **init**:

```
class Plugin:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    def __init__(self, iface):
    ...
    self.dlg.button.connect(self.open_new_dialog)
```

Of course you can do it on a different way. Ex. you can create `self.nd = NewDialog(self)` in main class in init and only `self.nd.show()` it in this function.
And remember about passing objects like parent (it is your main dialog window) and iface if you want to use them with this new window.

Comment: I have changed my code but something is still wrog. Here is an error which appears when clicking a button:
super(SymbolizacjaConfig, self).__init__(parent)
TypeError: QWidget(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'instance'

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about difficoult soulution and I just overwrote it all. It was so simple. I must just import dialog for second window, add a method to open new dialog and add a line in **init** to react when button pushed.